# How to put commas in my product attributes?

Tags: php, attributes

I inserted the code below in my content-product.php and the result is:

> 1 year2 year3 year4 year

How can I put commas in my attributes and change the year to yr?

```
<p class="availsize"><?php
echo "Available Sizes: ";
$subheadingvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_available-sizes');

  foreach ( $subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue ) {
   echo $subheadingvalue->name;
    }
?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a variable `$subheading` to collect all data with a `,`(comma) at the end. I did this because all the data will be separated by a comma along the a `,` at the end. Like `data1,data2,data3,`. Then the `trim` function is used to remove the `,` at the end.

```
<p class="availsize">
    <?php
        echo "Available Sizes: ";
        $subheadingvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_available-sizes');

        $subheading=''; //for collecting
        foreach ( $subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue ) {
            $subheading.= $subheadingvalue->name . ',';
        }
        echo trim($subheading, ',');
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi Jonju, thank you so much for helping. and the result was "Available Sizes: 1 year,3 years,5 years,7 years" its now okay but how can i add space after comma.

Comment: put an extra space after comma.this way  `',   '`

Comment: Thank you so much!